# pyapns - hexlified_token_str

Tags: python, apple-push-notifications

i try to test [pyapns](http://pyapns.org/).

There is a mention of the **hexlified_token_str** in the documentation.
My token is stored in base64 format.

I try to do this

```
>>> notify('myapp', base64.decodestring('Sl96FJtZbZDZECSP3EedQJbsXdtlV+LXWd4+jbzvbHM='), {'aps':{'alert': 'Hello!'}})
```

But I'm wrong.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pyapns/client.py", line 54, in notify
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pyapns/client.py", line 76, in _xmlrpc_thread
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/xmlrpclib.py", line 1147, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/xmlrpclib.py", line 1437, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/xmlrpclib.py", line 1201, in request
    return self._parse_response(h.getfile(), sock)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/xmlrpclib.py", line 1340, in _parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/xmlrpclib.py", line 787, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
  xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 8002: "Can't deserialize input: not well-formed (invalid token): line 9, column 18">
```

How do I do hexlified it correctly ?

Comment: i tried notify('myapp', binascii.hexlify(base64.decodestring('Sl96FJtZbZDZECSP3EedQJbsXdtlV+LXWd4+jbzvbHM=')),  {'aps':{'alert': 'Hello!'}}) but i wasn't notified !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was too late yesterday ...
It did the job :

```
binascii.hexlify(base64.decodestring('Sl96FJtZbZDZECSP3EedQJbsXdtlV+LXWd4+jbzvbHM='))
```

It was just an obsolete token !